# 2D array returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var term = [,];
term[0,0]="0";
term[0,1]="1";
term[1,0]="2";
term[1,1]="3";
alert(term[0,1]);
```

Returns 3, and I don't know why.
Logically, it should return 1, correct?

Comment: Its always recommended to read the docs before start writing code in a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **2D** it's meant `[[]]`, not `[,]` *[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/zitez/1/edit?js,console)*

```
var term = [[],[]];
term[0][0]="0";
term[0][2]="1";
term[1][0]="2";
term[1][3]="3";

console.log( term );          // [["0", "1"], ["2", "3"]]
console.log( term[0][1] );    // "1"
```

Also you can insert/append *keys* into an array using [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, when you have an expression like `a, b`, it will evaluate both `a` and `b` and the result of the expression will be `b`. You can confirm that like this

```
console.log((1, 2));
# 2
console.log((0, 1));
# 1
console.log((1, 0));
# 0
```

So,

```
term[0, 0] = "0";
term[0, 1] = "1";
term[1, 0] = "2";
term[1, 1] = "3";
```

was evaluated like this

```
term[0, 0] = term[0] = "0";
term[0, 1] = term[1] = "1";
term[1, 0] = term[0] = "2";
term[1, 1] = term[1] = "3";
```

So the actual array has got only `2` and `3`. Now, you are trying to access, `0, 1`, which is equivalent to

```
term[0, 1] = term[1]
```

That is why you are getting `3`.

To actually create a 2-D Array, you create a main array and keep adding subarrays to it, like this

```
var term = [];
term.push([0, 1]);
term.push([2, 3]);
```

Now, to access value at `0, 1`, you need to do like this

```
term[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript arrays don't work that way.

Here is an example that should work:

```
var term = []; // Create array
term[0] = ["0", "1"]; // What you referred to as [0,0] and [0,1]
term[1] = ["2", "3"]; // What you referred to as [1,0] and [1,1]

alert(term[0][1]); // Proper JavaScript way to access 2D array.
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6H5tm/).